# Python and Keras on windows using cygwin

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, keras

I'm following this a tutorial on how to set up Python,Keras and CUDA on windows (the tutorial is for windows 10, and I have windows 7, but I don't think it is the issue):

https://github.com/philferriere/dlwin

My current situation is a bit strange:

- When I use windows command line (CMD.exe), I can run python and then type `import keras` and it will be imported successfully, I even tried running some samples on NN and everything worked perfectly.
- When I do the same thing from Cygwin, I get `No module named keras`.

Just to make sure my Cygwin shell knows where keras is I've tried `pip install keras==1.2.2` from Cygwin.
And got:

```
Requirement already satisfied: keras==1.2.2 in d:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: theano in d:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from keras==1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in d:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from keras==1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in d:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from keras==1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in d:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from theano->keras==1.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in d:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from theano->keras==1.2.2)
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Could it be that your `site-packages` are not the same in Windows and Cygwin? How about $PATH/$PYTHONPATH?

Comment: I don't have envioronement variable called pythonpath, only path, that looks the same in cmd and cygwin.